# How to exclude the year-month string from my data?

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata

```
SELECT 
EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate)||EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) AS YEAR_MONTH,
FROM trnsact
WHERE YEAR_MONTH <> '2005 8'
```

1. Above is my sample code that is relevant to my question, it is run in **Teradata**.
2. So, I have got some tips from my online course that the "**||**" symbol can **join** the YEAR and MONTH of a date.
3. The thing is I don't know to how **exclude** certain value of this Year-month pair string. As in the code, I want to exclude 2005-08 from my data.
4. I have tried different version of ordering and styling,which I will list below. Nothing worked.
5. I also tried to use NOT IN function, which also didn't work.
6. I don't know how to search my problem, because what I know is what this symbol can do and I have no information about its name.
7. Also the result this || function output is of the styling like "2005 08".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) || EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) AS YEAR_MONTH
FROM trnsact
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) <> 2005 AND
      EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) <> 08
```

I don't know if EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) returns the data as `M` or `MM` , but if it doesn't work switch the comparsion to `8` instead of `08`

Comment: @dnoeth You are correct, fixed although it wouldn't really matter.

Comment: 1. Sagi I figure what you mean is:    
    where NOT (EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) = 2005 AND
                        EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) = 08)
Because the code you give there actually rule out the data of year 2005 and month,August which include values like 2005-01 and 2004-08 and that is not what I intend for.

2. The thing is, I want to exclude several year-month pairs , in which case, both of your methods @dnoeth would contain several lines of code and could be hard to read. 

3. Do we have a better solution?:)

Comment: @陈嘉奇: Readability is one thing, but efficiency is usually more important and `EXTRACT` plus typecast to a string for every row is not efficient. `EXTRACT(YEAR from saledate) * 100 + EXTRACT(MONTH from saledate) NOT IN (200508, ...)` is the best you can get, but will never use partitioning and is more expensive than multiple `NOT BETWEEN`.

Comment: @Dnoeth is correct, if you are handaling with big amount of data you should use his solution

Answer (score 0):

The resutling data type of `EXTRACT` is an `INTEGER`, if you concat there's an automatic typecast to a `VARCHAR(11)` with leading blanks and right aligned digits:

```
'       2016          3'
```

But there's no need to concat, either use two `EXTRACT` or even better:

```
WHERE saledate NOT BETWEEN DATE '2016-03-01' AND DATE '2016-03-31'
```

Now there's no calculation at all and the search condition might use an index or partitioning, too.